# Determine Network Adapter Type via WMI

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wmi-query

I'm using WMI (Win32_NetworkAdapter) and trying to get the details of attached physical network adapters either wired or wireless and avoid virtual adapters, etc.

Reading [this article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/11/04/find-only-physical-network-adapters-with-wmi-win32_networkadapter-class.aspx) it explains that you have to do some clever querying on WMI to eliminate virtual adapters and attempt to only return real physical adapters.

Reading [this post](http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/win32-programmer-wmi/t-is-network-adapter-wireless-346835.html) it explains that you can compare the text in the "Description" of the network adapter to see if it includes "Wireless", "802.11", or "WLAN", if it does, then most likely the adapter is a wireless adapter.

With today's .Net versions and other advancements, are these really the only two ways of determining on Windows XP+ if a network adapter is wired or wireless and is not a virtual adapter from VM software or the like?  If not, please explain.

Comment: Are you only looking for solutions that involve WMI?

Comment: Preferably, yes.  My existing project uses WMI with .Net quite extensively to get adapter information as it sits.  If there are other options, I'd like to know but unsure if I will implement.

Comment: Using WMI couldn't you just filter based on the `Win32_NetworkAdapter.PhysicalAdapter` (should be false if the interface is virtual) and then use the `AdapterTypeID` to determine if it is wired or wireless? I skimmed the article you posted and their criteria unreasonable.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Win32_NetworkAdapter.PhysicalAdapter Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, Windows 2000, and Windows NT 4.0:  This property is not available.  AdapterTypeID is not reliable as I have my laptop here and WMI returns it as non-wireless.

Answer (score 7):

You can use new WMI class **MSFT_NetAdapter** in **'root\StandardCimv2'** namespace. This class was introduced in **Windows 8**.

We can use property **ConnectorPresent** to filter only to physical adapters.
Next we must eliminate Wi-Fi adapters (which is present among physical adapters), we can use **InterfaceType** and/or **NdisPhysicalMedium** properties.

**InterfaceType** is defined by the Internet Assigned Names Authority (IANA) and for all ethernet-like interfaces is value **ethernetCsmacd (6)** (see https://www.iana.org/assignments/ianaiftype-mib/ianaiftype-mib).

In **NdisPhysicalMedium** is for ethernet adapters values **0** or **802.3 (14)**.

So my solution for this in C# is:

```
try
{
    var objectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\StandardCimv2", $@"select Name, InterfaceName, InterfaceType, NdisPhysicalMedium from MSFT_NetAdapter where ConnectorPresent=1"); //Physical adapter

    int count = 0;
    foreach (var managementObject in objectSearcher.Get())
    {
        //The locally unique identifier for the network interface. in InterfaceType_NetluidIndex format. Ex: Ethernet_2.
        string interfaceName = managementObject["InterfaceName"]?.ToString();
        //The interface type as defined by the Internet Assigned Names Authority (IANA).
        //https://www.iana.org/assignments/ianaiftype-mib/ianaiftype-mib
        UInt32 interfaceType = Convert.ToUInt32(managementObject["InterfaceType"]);
        //The types of physical media that the network adapter supports.
        UInt32 ndisPhysicalMedium = Convert.ToUInt32(managementObject["NdisPhysicalMedium"]);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(interfaceName) &&
            interfaceType == 6 &&       //ethernetCsmacd(6) --for all ethernet-like interfaces, regardless of speed, as per RFC3635
            (ndisPhysicalMedium == 0 || ndisPhysicalMedium == 14))   //802.3
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
catch (ManagementException)
{
    //Run-time requirements WMI MSFT_NetAdapter class is included in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012
}
```

Comment: This is good. Thank you.  Too bad we're still using Windows 7 Embedded on all our devices still :(

Comment: @HolaJan Can we also port the code above also in C++ (barring the C# constructs)? What I mean is to know if there is another C++ library/DLL that instantiates same management objects instances and object search mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

I see this is an old question, but I have [found an answer elsewhere](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/12/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-identify-network-adapter-characteristics.aspx#comments) on the internet which gives a description of how this can be done (scroll all the way down to the comments).

The comment-er's technique allows the identification of WiFi and Bluetooth interfaces, where all other types may be grouped together. If the goal is only to separate the WiFi from the Ethernet adapters, it should be sufficient.

The queries are (Powershell sample):

```
$nics = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root/CIMV2" -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter"
$types = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root/WMI" -Query "SELECT * FROM MSNdis_PhysicalMediumType"
```

The first query is the common approach which will provide the list of adapters. As previously noted, it can be filtered to only include valid, physical devices by a number of other selection criteria.

The second query returns a WMI object with a `NdisPhysicalMediumType` property, which according to the linked site, has the value **9** for WiFi, **10** for Bluetooth, and **0** for Ethernet and most other adapter types.

It looks like joining these two queries has to be done manually in script using the `Name` or `Description` property of the first query and the `InstanceName` property of the second.

Comment: The technet link is no longer working, here's the updated link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-identify-network-adapter-characteristics/

And a web archive as backup: https://web.archive.org/web/20220419011251/https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-identify-network-adapter-characteristics/

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter where NetConnectionID LIKE "%Wireless%" or NetConnectionID LIKE "%Wi-Fi%"
```

Comment: String searches are simply not reliable enough.