# looking for a MAC address of a physical adapter

Tags: windows, delphi, networking, wmi, delphi-xe

I would like to use a unique identifier to determine whether my application moved to a different computer. The MAC address seems to be suitable for this purpose. The code I use is this:

```
Procedure TForm4.GetMacAddress;
var item: TListItem;
    objWMIService : OLEVariant;
    colItems      : OLEVariant;
    colItem       : OLEVariant;
    oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
    iValue        : LongWord;
    wmiHost, root, wmiClass: string;
    i: Int32;

  function GetWMIObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch;
  var
    chEaten: Integer;
    BindCtx: IBindCtx;//for access to a bind context
    Moniker: IMoniker;//Enables you to use a moniker object
  begin
    OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
    OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, Moniker));//Converts a string into a moniker that identifies the object named by the string
    OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));//Binds to the specified object
  end;

begin
   wmiHost       := '.';
   root          := 'root\CIMV2';
   wmiClass      := 'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration';
   objWMIService := GetWMIObject(Format('winmgmts:\\%s\%s',[wmiHost,root]));
   colItems      := objWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT * FROM %s',[wmiClass]),'WQL',0);
   oEnum         := IUnknown(colItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
   i := 0;
   while oEnum.Next(1, colItem, iValue) = 0 do
   begin
      Item := View.Items.Add;
      item.Caption := Copy (colItem.Caption, 2, 8);

      Item.SubItems.Add (colItem.Description);
      Item.SubItems.Add (colItem.ServiceName);
      Item.SubItems.Add (VarToStrNil (colItem.MACAddress));
      if (VarToStrNil(colItem.MACAddress) <> '')
         then Item.SubItems.Add ('yes')
         else Item.SubItems.Add ('no');
      if colItem.IPEnabled
         then Item.SubItems.Add ('yes')
         else Item.SubItems.Add ('no');
     Item.SubItems.Add (VarToStrNil (colItem.SettingID));
     Item.SubItems.Add (IntToStr (colItem.InterfaceIndex));
   end; // if
end; // GetMacAddress //
```

My machine has one network port, but this code finds 18 network related ports/things/whatever. Among them there are four MAC adresses. I presume that a network port should be IP enabled so that leaves two left (labeled MAC in the image). Is it correct to assume that of the ports thus filtered, the one with the lowest index is the hardware port?

[image]

**Edit** in the snapshot above the Realtek adapter is the only physical adapter in the machine. The other adapter is the VirtualBox virtual adapter. The answer of TLama identifies these two adapters, but is there a way to find the address of the only Physical (Realtek) adapter?

**Update 1** EJP pointed out that the MAC address can be changed. This somewhat undermines my purpose, but as I am looking for a solution that fits most situations I decided  to live with it.

TLama and TOndrej pointed to several solutions. Both end up with a situation that a physical adapter could not be found without any doubt.

**Update 2** TLama's excellent reading list shows that there is probably not a certain way to determine the physical adapter. The article mentioned in the first bullet shows how to shrink the amount of adapters based on some simple assumptions. The article in the third bullet shows how to select the adapter connected to the PCI bus, which is in fact exactly what I wanted to know. There are some weird exceptions mentioned in the article but I think this will provide an answer in most cases.

Thank you all for your contributions!

Comment: Good point, I have adopted your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: The MAC address is not suitable for this purpose. It can be changed by the user.

Comment: The Windows Control Panel for a start.

Comment: Sorry, Couldn't find it.

Comment: Networking properties of an adapter. The later the version of Windows, the deeper you have to drill. But it's there. Unix and Limux too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class instead. It has the `PhysicalAdapter` member. The following example should list you the MAC addresses of physical adapters:

```
program Program1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, ActiveX, ComObj, Variants;

procedure GetWin32_NetworkAdapterInfo;
const
  WbemUser = '';
  WbemPassword = '';
  WbemComputer = 'localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  ElementCount: LongWord;
  FWMIService: OleVariant;
  FWbemObject: OleVariant;
  EnumVariant: IEnumVARIANT;
  FSWbemLocator: OleVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OleVariant;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet := FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE PhysicalAdapter = 1', 'WQL', wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  EnumVariant := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while EnumVariant.Next(1, FWbemObject, ElementCount) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('MACAddress %s', [VarToStr(FWbemObject.MACAddress)]));
    FWbemObject := Unassigned;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_NetworkAdapterInfo;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
  except
    on E:EOleException do
      Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
  end;
  Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
  Readln;
end.
```

Based on the code generated by the [`WMI Delphi Code Creator`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/).

***Update:***

You are actually trying to filter out the adapters which belongs to virtual machines, what is not that easy since they are simulated like to be as physical ones (you can even see them in Device Manager as the physical adapters), so you cannot distinguish them e.g.:

- by the `DHCPEnabled` member of the [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, because even virtual machines might be configured so they get IP address from a DHCP server
- by the `AdapterTypeId` member of the [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, since there is no special type for virtual adapters
- by the `PhysicalAdapter` member of the [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, because they are being simulated to be physical

***Additional reading:***

- [`Find only physical network adapters with WMI Win32_NetworkAdapter class`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/11/04/find-only-physical-network-adapters-with-wmi-win32_networkadapter-class.aspx) - this article has a good analysis and it might fulfill your needs (I haven't tested it though)
- [`How to determine physical network adapter type using WMI`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114455/determine-network-adapter-type-via-wmi) - this question is opened at this time and it is actually exactly what you need
- [`How to determine MAC Address of the physical network card`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567377/how-to-determine-mac-address-of-the-actual-physical-network-card-not-virtual) - there is one idea I like and I would personally stick to when I'd be 100% sure that the root of the `PNPDeviceID` member
  of the [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class for hardware adapters cannot start with something different from the `PCI\\` (actually the same I was thinking about when I was comparing the data)

Comment: This yields exactly the two MAC addresses with IPEnabled in my question. I wonder how I can distinguish between the real network adapter (Realtek) and the virtual network adapter from VirtualBox. My question was not clear at that point. I'll add to it.

Comment: Basically I would say this might be distinguished e.g. in `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` by the `DHCPEnabled` member, but even those virtual adapters might be configured to get the IP address from DHCP server. There is also `PNPDeviceID` which starts with the `PCI\...` but it's still not so significant. In [`this`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18135/Getting-the-Network-Adaptor-MAC-Address-with-WMI) example they used `AdapterTypeId`, however the virtual adapters has no special type for it, so it's also not a solution.

Comment: Seems I was thinking the [`similar way`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/11/04/find-only-physical-network-adapters-with-wmi-win32_networkadapter-class.aspx). I'm afraid those adapters are by Windows handled like a real physical network adapters, so without this tricky way it's impossible to distinguish them from a hardware ones.

Comment: I did experiment with the IP Helper library that TOndrej pointed at. The AdapterInfo struct has too few info as well. It is interesting code though, if you don't want to depend on WMI.

Comment: I was hoping more for the `PNPDeviceID` where the root would be `PCI\...` for instance, but I don't know if this would fit for USB adapters (if there are some), but it's still not so smooth solution. The virtual adapters are just like the real hardware ones, so it's quite difficult to distinguish them. I was looking for similar topics about this, but it seems no one solved this in a clean way.

Comment: Wew, thanks for the additional reading! However, they all shatter at my not being able to perform a query with a WHERE clause. 'SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE Manufacturer!=''Microsoft''' returns 'invalid query' (all single quotes, not so visible in comment I noticed, tried double quotes, same result). Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The `Manufacturer` is in the [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, not `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`, so it should be `SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE Manufacturer != "Microsoft"`. Anyway, the best you can do is to download the latest RRUZ's [`WMI Delphi Code Creator`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/), it includes also a query editor, where you can build the queries as well as generate a complete Delphi code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for the pointer to RRUZ. I use the PNPDeviceID now, if that does not yield anything it is probably a virtual machine and I take the first vailable. To test whether it works in all circumstances I should really test 100's of machines. Anyhow, this answers my question, thank you very much for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API from the [IP Helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) library. For a Delphi translation, [Magenta Systems IP Helper Component](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magiphlp.asp) looks good at first glance.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Interesting code, but as far as I can see resulting in about the same kind od output as of the 'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration' WMI class, in the end resulting in the same output: two ports that act as physical adapter.